# Change display of DateTime in MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Trx.TradeDate, new { @class = "economicTextBox", propertyName = "Trx.TradeDate", dontRegisterNewIndication = true })%>
```

Since this is a `TextBoxFor`, I can't just change the way it's displayed (I don't think?), because I have to have that specific property value I'm binding this to.

This is displaying the full `DateTime` though - `5/18/2011 10:21:22 AM`

How do I get it to only display the `5/18/2011` portion?

Should I do it through Javascript? This field is made as a JQuery DatePicker field as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an EditorTemplate for DateTime, either in the EditorTemplates folder in your view, or in /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates.

Then call `<%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateTimeProp) %>`.

\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\DateTime.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<DateTime?>" %>
<%= Html.TextBox(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty), Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") : string.Empty) %>
```

Alternately:

You can also add your own HtmlHelper extension, like `DateTimeTextBoxFor`. Unfortunately, the templates used by the `____For` default extensions have a rather static template.

Another Alternative:

You can use Data Attributes to control the data type and format, however, I think you still need to use `EditorFor` to get those to work (although, it wouldn't require a separate ASCX file).

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
public DateTime DateTimeProp { get; set; }

<%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateTimeProp) %>
```

Comment: I wanted to stay away from creating another user control but yeah this would work.

Comment: The nice thing about using the editor template approach is you could do your jQuery UI script init stuff right there, if you wanted to. Plus, it saves you the hassle of making sure each DateTime property is properly attributed or otherwise manually formatted. Although, I wish `___For` respected DisplayFormatAttribute (Maybe it does in MVC3? I haven't checked).